# how to use R-selenium to click a expand list

Tags: web-scraping, rselenium

Right now I'm trying to scraping data from [this website](https://www.change.org/p/mayor-jacob-frey-justice-for-george-floyd?pt=AVBldGl0aW9uAAoFVgEAAAAAXwl8a6DlqZo4OWJiZDA5OA%3D%3D&source_location=topic_page). I want to use selenium to click this["View all updates" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DKkA.png). I used SelectorGadget and XPath helper to find the css selector and xpath of it, but both or them failed.
My codes are below:

```
loadmore <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', ".js-toggle-expand-updates")
loadmore <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*div[@class='js-toggle-expand-updates']")
loadmore$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. The excat class of the button cannot be found through SelectorGadget, it is the first word of class in the code below

```
<div style="cursor: pointer;" class = "box box-basic type-s pbxxs mbn mtm xs-mts phm xs-phs bg-brighter border-none-a-xs js-toggle-expand-updates">
```

which is "box"